# Expectation and autocorrelation function of a Wiener process (Brownian motion)

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, expected-value, brownian-motion

Let $\{W(t): t \geqslant 0\}$ be a Wiener process (Brownian motion) with variance parameter $σ^2 = 1$.
Define the process $\{Z(t): t \geqslant 0\}$ by  $Z(t) = e^{-ct} W(e^{2ct})$,  with $c > 0$.

1. We must compute the expectation function of $Z(t)$.
   I was wondering if $Z(t)$ is also a Wiener process, which would imply that its expectation function is always equal to $0$.
2. We must compute the autocorrelation function of $Z(t)$.
   I was wondering if I can use the independent increments property of a Wiener process to split the formula of autocorrelation as follows : $R(t, t+T) = E(Z(t) Z(t+T)) = E(Z(t)) E(Z(t+T))$.

Comment: Regarding the second question: is it true that $\mathbb{E}[W(t) W(t+T)] = \mathbb{E}[W(t)] \mathbb{E}[W(t+T)]$?

Comment: I think it is as W has independent increments but I don't know if I understand well what do independent increments imply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first question, we have
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}[Z(t)] &= \mathbb{E}[e^{-ct}W(e^{2ct})] = e^{-ct} \mathbb{E}[W(e^{2ct})] = 0.
\end{align*}

For the second question, we have
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}[Z(t)Z(t+T)] &= \mathbb{E}[(e^{-ct}W(e^{2ct}))\cdot (e^{-c(t+T)}W(e^{2c(t+T)})) ] \\
&= e^{-2ct-cT} \mathbb{E}[W(e^{2ct})W(e^{2c(t+T)})].
\end{align*}
Now, to compute $\mathbb{E}[W(e^{2ct})W(e^{2c(t+T)})]$, we have
\begin{align*}\mathbb{E}[W(e^{2ct})W(e^{2c(t+T)})]&= \mathbb{E}[W(e^{2ct})(W(e^{2c(t+T)})-W(e^{2ct}) + W(e^{2ct}))] \\  
&= \mathbb{E}[W(e^{2ct})(W(e^{2c(t+T)})-W(e^{2ct}))] + \mathbb{E}[W(e^{2ct})^2].
\end{align*}
Since Brownian motion has independent increments, we know that $W(s)$ is independent of $W(S)-W(s)$ for all $0 \le s \le S$.  Applying this to the first term with $s = e^{2ct}$ and $S = e^{2c(t+T)}$, we see

\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}[W(e^{2ct})(W(e^{2c(t+T)})-W(e^{2ct}))] &= \mathbb{E}[W(e^{2ct})] \mathbb{E}[W(e^{2c(t+T)})-W(e^{2ct})] = 0.
\end{align*}

Since $W(e^{2ct}) \sim N(0,e^{2ct})$, we know that $\mathbb{E}[W(e^{2ct})^2] = e^{2ct}$, and so
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}[W(e^{2ct})W(e^{2c(t+T)})]&= e^{2ct}.
\end{align*}
Thus, we have

\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}[Z(t)Z(t+T)] &= e^{-2ct-cT} \mathbb{E}[W(e^{2ct})W(e^{2c(t+T)})] \\
&= e^{-2ct - cT} (e^{2ct}) \\
&= e^{-cT}.
\end{align*}